# Calling Map Reduce in a Hive UDFT

Tags: mapreduce, hive

Is there a way to have a udft call custom mappers and reducers that would be run on the cluster?

Answer (score 0):

Most people use the SELECT TRANSFORM feature to do this sort of thing, see https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Transform